# Where in the last version of unity grid and snap settings and how to change grid size?

Tags: unity-game-engine, interface

[I don't have grid and snap settings in the edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOJfO.png)

[I have this little tab, but scale here do nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZiwN.png)

[Greed Visual same useless to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOPRY.png)

[Searching same do nothing, with search of "snap" i have same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxzAX.png)

Sorry for bad English <3

Comment: in window tab same, idk, why unity need to delete good working tab for split they to ALL of the interface :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a dropdown in the top bar in "scene view". It looks like a ruler.
Here's a picture of it: [picture of button in SceneView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Pu5.png)